# Edit Incoming Packets On a Specific Port

Tags: udp, packet-sniffers, packets, tcp

I know there are various programs that sniff packets like WireShark, but I'm pretty sure you can only view the data. I want to know if it's possible to *edit* incoming packets. I'm not sure if packets are the right term. I just want to edit incoming data that is recieved through the internet and who's destination is a specific application. Let's say I am playing an online game. As it loads my computer, it is recieving information like "This person has 10 coins in their money pouch". Obviously not exactly like *that* but you get the point. I would like to be able to change the data so it is say 100 instead of 10. I know something like this would be possible if you were to do this: Imagine my computer is connected to the internet with an ethernet cord. There is a device attached to the ethernet cord which recieves the data and changes it and then lets it continue to my computer. I would just like to know if this is possible, and how it could be accomplished.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it, is one of 2 ways:
 1.

1. If your application supports it set up a HTTP Proxy on your machine and you could software like burp / Fiddler to mess with the data
2. If not (the protocol is not HTTP) you could use either one of 2 options i'v tried [Both based on Hooking the API calls from the application to the OS]:

   - EchoMirage software that allow messing around with the packets
   - [Bit more advanced: ] There is a debugger named OllyDbg which has a plugin named Universal Hooker; it enables to hook any window API function and execute a python script on demend. the uHooker contains examples for how to hook WSASend and WSARecive (which are the API functions used in windows sockets).